# Getting an error even after callling suspend function from coroutine scope

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an async process in my android app and I am using a co-routine scope to call a suspend function. But I am getting this error.

> Suspend function 'getByTimeType' should be called only from a
> coroutine or another suspend function

This is the code giving me error:
class WidgetProvider : HomeWidgetProvider() {

```
private var job: Job = Job()
private val scope = CoroutineScope(job + Dispatchers.Main)

override fun onUpdate(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetIds: IntArray,
    widgetData: SharedPreferences
) {

    Log.d("debugging", "widget loaded")
    appWidgetIds.forEach { widgetId ->
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).apply {
            val todosRemoteView = RemoteViews.RemoteCollectionItems.Builder()

            scope.launch {
                val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    AppDatabase::class.java, "db"
                ).build()
                val todosDAO = db.TodoDAO()
                val todos: List<Todo> = todosDAO.getByTimeType("day")
            }

            Log.d("debugging", "update is triggered");

            setRemoteAdapter(
                R.id.todos_list,
                todosRemoteView
                    .build()
            )

        }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views)
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It looks good to me. Are you sure the problem occurs in the provided code line and not in another place? Maybe IDE messed its caches or something. Could you try to build using Gradle to see if it also fails?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @broot, actually this was super silly. using the suspend function at a different location where I hadn't wrapped it in co-routine scope was giving throwing this error.